# Mutually borrowing data between futures

Tags: rust

I am writing an asynchronous program for downloading items from peer and I am trying to keep track of the number of active peers. I have the following implementation:

```rust
use futures::future::join_all;
use futures::future::join;
use std::time::Duration;

async fn download(_i: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // can return io error if connection failed etc.
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)).await;
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let peers = vec!["one", "two", "three"];
    
    let active_peers = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(0));
    
    let workers = join_all(peers.into_iter().map(|peer| {
        let active_peers = active_peers.clone();
        async move {
            *active_peers.lock().unwrap() += 1;
            download(peer).await.unwrap();
            *active_peers.lock().unwrap() -= 1;
        }
    }));
    
    let result = async move {
        for _ in 0..5 {
           tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
           println!("active peers {:?}", active_peers.lock().unwrap());
        }
    };
    
    join(workers, result).await; // should start all download workers at the same time
    
    Ok(())
}
```

output:

```
active peers 3
active peers 3
active peers 0
active peers 0
active peers 0
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab08c8ab9aa4a3200d6be9743a4f887c)

However, I have structures like `Vec<u8>`, which I would prefer passing as a reference instead of doing like this: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db768a3be94612b39bd2bab3ef399f40). I believe running `Vec<u8>::clone` will make a copy of the heap allocation, unless I wrap the vector in an `Rc` or `Arc` ? Does this causes more indirection than mutually borrowing the vector between the futures?

Since I am using [`join`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/struct.Join.html) instead of [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html), I am trying to take advantage of the non-`'static` requirement of using `join` instead of `spawn`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638710/when-should-you-use-tokiojoin-over-tokiospawn/69639836#comment123092596_69639766), i.e. not needing to own the data inside the future scope. This is similar to how [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/fn.scope.html) work, see [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Athread%3B%0A%0Alet%20mut%20a%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0Alet%20mut%20x%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0Athread%3A%3Ascope(%7Cs%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20s.spawn(%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22hello%20from%20the%20first%20scoped%20thread%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20We%20can%20borrow%20%60a%60%20here.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbg!(%26a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20s.spawn(%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22hello%20from%20the%20second%20scoped%20thread%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20We%20can%20even%20mutably%20borrow%20%60x%60%20here%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20because%20no%20other%20threads%20are%20using%20it.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%3D%20a%5B0%5D%20%2B%20a%5B2%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22hello%20from%20the%20main%20thread%22)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20After%20the%20scope%2C%20we%20can%20modify%20and%20access%20our%20variables%20again%3A%0Aa.push(4)%3B%0Aassert_eq!(x%2C%20a.len())%3B%0A%7D&edition=2021).

Is there a way to make this compile without the `move` keyword? I get the following compile error with just `async { ... }`:

```
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `active_peers`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:20:15
   |
20 |           async {
   |  _______________^
21 | |             *active_peers.lock().unwrap() += 1;
   | |              ------------ `active_peers` is borrowed here
22 | |             download(peer).await.unwrap();
23 | |             *active_peers.lock().unwrap() -= 1;
24 | |         }
   | |_________^ may outlive borrowed value `active_peers`
   |
```

if I remove the constraint of keeping track of the number of active peers, this compiles without any errors:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let peers = vec!["one", "two", "three"];
    
    let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    let workers = join_all(peers.into_iter().map(|peer| {
        async {
            download(peer, &v).await.unwrap();
        }
    }));
    
    let result = async {
        for _ in 0..5 {
           tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
           println!("active peers {:?}", 0);
        }
    };
    
    join(workers, result).await; // should start all download workers at the same time
    
    Ok(())
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d592f4d2d3cfd9709e2b7082cf8d0dd6)

Which is intuitively how I would like it to work.

Other suggestions on how to keep track of the number of non-failed futures inside a [`futures::futures::JoinAll`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/struct.JoinAll.html) is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `move` is only necessary for `active_peers`. You can just replace `v` with a reference instead of a clone and it'll work:

```rust
let active_peers = active_peers.clone();
let v = &v; // we only need to move a reference in
async move {
    *active_peers.lock().unwrap() += 1;
    download(peer, v).await.unwrap();
    *active_peers.lock().unwrap() -= 1;
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65aa0d8a0eeeb05a5b36ea570fc42dbf)

As a side note, taking a `&[T]` as a function argument [is almost always better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/5923139) than taking `&Vec<T>`.